# Call LINK in rest API (php)

Tags: php, rest, guzzle

Looking into a `REST API` which mentions a LINK call. I am only familiar with `post`, `get` etc, not LINK and in a `Guzzle` environment, so trying to find more information on this and how to call LINK in `Guzzle`. Anybody know this?

https://penneo.readme.io/docs/sending-a-casefile-1

```
LINK /api/v1/folders/<folder id>/casefiles/<your casefile id>
```

Comment: LINK is a HTTP method that didn't make it into newer versions of the HTTP specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068 . It was removed in the June 1999 spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: @Evert I hadn't even heard of it, but OP's docs do indicate it's being used in the API.

Answer (score 2):

https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/request.html

> You can create custom HTTP requests that use non-standard HTTP methods using the `createRequest()` method of a client object.

```
$request = $client->createRequest('COPY', 'http://example.com/foo', array(
    'Destination' => 'http://example.com/bar',
    'Overwrite'   => 'T'
));
$response = $request->send();
```